# Splitting a phone number using .split function

Tags: javascript, split

I have a phone number value being returned from an api and Im trying to split its values into three sections. But the phone number is formatted in a way that is making it hard to understand how to apply the .split function the number is returned like this `(AAA) BBB-CCCC` .
The value I am having trouble isolating is the middle three numbers
for the first one I have this working

```
phone.split(" ")[0] //returns AAA
phone.split("-")[1] // returns CCCC
```

but I cannot crack the middle numbers should I not use .split for the middle value?

Comment: Use a regex to split on space or dash

Comment: "(AAA) BBB-CCCC".match(/\((.{3})\)\s(.{3})-(.{4})/)

Comment: Wouldn’t the first split return `'(AAA)'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved with split. Split() returns an array of substrings. First you split the string using the space delimiter and afterwards using '-' as delimiter.

```js
let string = "(AAA) BBB-CCCC";
let desiredResult = string.split(" ")[1].split("-")[0];
console.log(desiredResult);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple regex with [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
var phoneNrParts = '(AAA) BBB-CCCC'.match(/\((.*)\) (.*)-(.*)/);

console.log('part 1: ', phoneNrParts[1]);
console.log('part 2: ', phoneNrParts[2]);
console.log('part 3: ', phoneNrParts[3]);
```

or you could use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with the same regex as above, but as mentioned in the comments, a match is nicer in this case

```js
var phoneNrParts = '(AAA) BBB-CCCC'.split(/\((.*)\) (.*)-(.*)/);

console.log('part 1: ', phoneNrParts[1]);
console.log('part 2: ', phoneNrParts[2]);
console.log('part 3: ', phoneNrParts[3]);
```

learn more about the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/No8at8/1